# How do I get my .txt file that I put in my workspace to show up in Finder?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have Eclipse Oxygen Release 4.7.0. and I use High Sierra OS X on a Macbook Air. My problem is that I have a .txt file inside of my workspace folder but it doesn't show up in the package explorer. How do I get it to show up?

Comment: Refresh folder does not help?

Comment: Is it in a project? Only files in projects are shown. You may need to refresh the project,

Comment: Yes, refresh folder helped to solve the problem.

Comment: You can enable _Window > Preferences: General > Workspace: Refresh using native hooks or pooling_ to avoid each time a file is added or deleted not by Eclipse to do a refresh (F5) manually.